# Get coordinates from gridview rows to draw on a canvas with Raphael.js

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, raphael

I have to draw some shapes depending on the status of the row. For them to work in IE I had to use Raphael javascript library. I'm using ASP.NET and C# for the codebehind. The way to draw is by coordinates, how can I get the coordinates of the rows so I can draw something outside the gridview, at it's side?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using jQuery for this.  The jQuery api has a `.position()`, and `.offset()` method which would give you a top and left value.  See [jQuery Tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials), [.position()](http://api.jquery.com/position/), and [.offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) for specifics.

**Edit**

If jQuery isn't your bag, then I found a post that includes an example function done in JavaScript: [Dynamically retrieve Html element (X,Y) position with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/dynamically-retrieve-html-element-x-y-position-with-javascript).

Comment: Is there anyway to do it WITHOUT jQuery? I've never used it and I'd prefer to do it with things I'm familiar with :/

Comment: Updated to include a reference to another stack post which may help.